# Django forms adding class attribute from the constructor

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

As you can see in the code sample below, I'm trying to add that multiple choice field from my constructor (instead of doing it like in the commented line) but it doesn't seem to work, doesn't matter if it's before or after the call of super().

Any advices on how i can add that attribute from my constructor?

```
class PageForm(forms.Form):
    # answers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Answer.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.answers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Answer.objects.all())
         super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.answers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Answer.objects.all())
```

P.S. I know it might be irrelevant for this example, but I need this thing for a more complex thing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields need to be added after super. Instead self.answers, try self.fields['answers']

Comment: Dude, you saved my day (not sure, but i guess also my life ). 
**Thank you**